# Two Rows of Weighted Buttons

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am trying to render the main menu screen with four buttons, two rows of two buttons, that are weighted toward the bottom of the page. The only problem is that the top row of buttons covers the bottom row. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    tools:context="MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_2" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_4" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Wrap your root LinearLayout inside a FrameLayout or ConstraintLayout and set the gravity or constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only thing you have to  do is setting the orientation of the root LinearLayout to "vertical".

The orientation of the root LinearLayout is "horizontal",and the width of the two LinearLayout that contains in the root LinearLayout are "match_parent", so the top row of buttons will always cover the bottom row.